# 'Internal Error' when trying to set up connection between BigQuery and Cloudsql

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

Following the steps in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries#setting_up_database_connections after the API was activated, I tried to set up a connection between our BigQuery database and our Postgresql CloudSQL database. I entered everything correctly:

[image]

When I try to connect it, I get the following error, without any error code or other information as to why it might have went wrong:

[image]

Comment: I tried to reproduced your scenario and it looks like an internal issue which needs further investigation. Currently, I saw that the Bigquery team is working on it through a [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/139429606) case. All the communication will take place there.

Comment: This doesn't happen when the connection and PostgreSQL instance location is in US region. Connection=US and PostgreSQL instance location is us-central1